# Asp.net SelectMethod not firing on second submit click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that contains search inputs and a submit button.  The problem is that the SelectMethod is not firing if it is clicked twice with the same search criteria.  Thus, am not able to fetch new data from the db.  Am pretty sure it is caching the request.  The problem is that I don't know how to fix it.  I tried to disable the cache on the ObjectDataSource, but it didn't work

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="button floatr" Text="Search" />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="extendedGridView" AllowPaging="True"
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2"
            EmptyDataText="No Records Found"> ... </asp:GridView>

        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetTransaction" TypeName="Tx.Class.HelperFunctions">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxSearchTransactionType" Name="transactionType" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxStartDate" Name="startDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxEndDate" Name="endDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Code inside HelperFunctions.cs:

```
public IEnumerable<Transaction> GetTransaction(String transactionType,String startDate, String endDate)
    { ... }
```

Comment: Could you please show me the implementation in click event handler of submit button?

Comment: I edited my question to show you the structure, there is no code behind taking care of the submit button.

Comment: OK, but you have "GetTransaction" method, don't you? Which type will be returned from that method? You may provide us the code.

Comment: The problem is that the GetTransaction is not firing the second time with the same criteria. ie: if you input your search and your click submit it will fire, click a second time and its not firing, i think its caching, thats the only explanation I can come up with...

Comment: In actually, if the search criterias are the same, it doesn't need to do the **GetTransaction** again and again, and the result must still be the same in GridView, **ObjectDataSource** works like that.

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't want it to behave it like that because a new transaction might be inserted to the database right before the second click.  So I want to fetch it on the search.